# How can I convert private pdb to public pdb?

Tags: symbols, pdb-files

I have private pdb file and I have to convert it to a public one. Is there tool for it?

Comment: There are several types of pdb files (e.g. Palm database)  - which one do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a stripped pdb file that doesn't contain; Type information, Line number information, Per-object file CodeView symbols such as those for functions, locals, and static data. See the [/PDBSTRIPPED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y87kw2fd%28VS.80%29.aspx) compiler option.

**EDIT:** There does appear to be a utility that is part of the DDK that can convert a full symbol file to a stripped symbol file it is called [BinPlace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542210.aspx) the forum I found the information on suggested there might be problems with certain versions of the utility so be warned ([forum article](http://www.msusenet.com/archive/topic.php/t-1871526865.html)).

Comment: Unfortunately, rebuilding is not an option. I have to strip it from an existing symbol file.

Answer (score 11):

Use [PDBCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560131%28VS.85%29.aspx).
pdbcopy is part of the Debugging Tools for Windows which is available through the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8279)