# Best way to strip off symbols

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, gcc, symbols

Last week I released the Linux and windows version of an application.

And after the release we realized that the symbols were not stripped off, and my manager thinks (and I disagree) that it might allow the user to understand our algorithm.

Anyway, now, I will have to clean-up the symbols and re-release the application.

My question,

1. What is the best way to strip symbols in Linux?
2. What is the best way to strip symbols in Windows?

Comment: I think that debugging symbols _could_ help people to understand your algorithm. If they examine the call stack at various points in your program's execution, and they can see descriptive function names, then...

Comment: Depending on how your app is built, stripping could also reduce your app footprint by a whole lot (especially if you use a whole lot of static libraries)! In general stripping is good practice for anything you ship.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With Visual C++ (and other Microsoft compilers) on Windows, symbols aren't part of the binaries.  Instead, they are stored in separate files called "Program Database" files (.pdb files).  Just don't provide the .pdb files.

With the GNU toolchain you would use `strip` to remove symbols from the binaries.

Comment: If you have private ms pdb's and want to convert them to public ones, you can chek this answer [private to public](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525648/how-can-i-convert-private-pdb-to-public-pdb/1526031#1526031)

Answer (score 23):

For the GNU toolchain, there exists a cool sleight of hand:

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug yourprogram ../somepath/yourprogram.dbg
strip yourprogram
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=../somepath/yourprogram.dbg yourprogram
```

Now you can zip the folder your program is in (or pack it into an installer or whatever), there will be no more debug symbols in it.
**BUT :** If you launch the debugger or if you run a tool like `addr2line` or `obdump`, the tool will (thanks to the debuglink info) automagically know where to find the symbols and load them.

Which is awesome, because it means you have the benefits of having symbols on your end, without distributing them to the user.