# How to remove sensitive data from compiled binary (.dll)? Visual Studio 2015 (cpp)

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, linker

I'm building a DLL, and I want to make static analysis of this .dll harder as possible. But whats the hell, I can see full paths to my (SOME) .cpp and .h files as is if I open compiled .dll in notepad. I can see definitions of (SOME) functions, no decompilation required lol, its visible. Sample:

```
void __cdecl Core::Context::Shutdown(void)
void __cdecl U::Read(unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,char *)
C:\Git\Repo\Games/XXX/GameApi.h
```

and etc, etc.
I'm not a newbie and I understand a difference between Debug/Release compilation. I don't care about my hardcoded strings in binary, I know how to hide it. But common, function prototypes and paths to files? They should not be in compiled .dll.

I'm using

- *Release* configuration,
- *x64* Platform,
- C/C++ -> General -> **Debug information format** -> None
- C/C++ -> Code Generation -> **Runtime library** -> Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)
- C/C++ -> Language -> **Enable Run-Time Type Information** -> No (/GR-)
- Linker -> Debugging -> **Generate Debug Info** -> No

**THOSE OPTIONS REMOVED A LOT SENSITIVE INFO FROM .DLL BUT NOT ALL!**

Full command line for compiler:

```
/GS /GL /W3 /Gy- /Zc:wchar_t /Gm- /O1 /sdl- /Fd"x64\Release\vc140.pdb" 
/Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" 
/errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /GR- /Gd /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc 
/nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Os /Fp"x64\Release\Dll_x64.pch"
```

Full command line for linker:

```
/OUT:"C:\Git\Repo\Games\XXX\Dll_x64.dll" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental 
/NXCOMPAT /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" 
"winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" 
"oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" 
/IMPLIB:"C:\Git\Repo\Games\XXX\Dll_x64.lib" /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF 
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" 
/ManifestFile:"x64\Release\Dll_x64.dll.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF 
/ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Someone please explain, why my function prototypes and paths to CPP/H files are appeared in compiled .dll. How can I avoid it.

Comment: Provide some [MCVE]. You are *not* coding any compiler, so the `compiler-construction` tag is wrong. You might want some kind of [strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_(Unix)) utility. I don't know its equivalent on Windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to strip off symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751220/best-way-to-strip-off-symbols).

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I've read that question, its related to Unix systems. Provided answer about windows there is wrong.

Comment: If it is very sensible code, you may consider a software protection like e.g. [CodeMeter](https://www.wibu.com/products/codemeter.html). This may look like advertising but I'm not employee of this company (though I must admit we are a satisfied customer). ;-)

Comment: @EatingPeopleIsFun why wrong? That was answered by the legendary member James McNellis, so I guess that's right.